# Access to singleton properties (WPF Binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, singleton

I've encountred a confusing problem while developping a user library in c# in which i've created two classes that implement an interface that is called by the API as a separated plugin...

(that means that after the compilation the API detect 2 plugins although they are from same project)

What i'm trying to do is to enable communication between those two plugins. Accuratly i want to transfer an object (it's reference not a copy) from a plugin to another... but i'm failing!

I tried to make one of those plugins Singleton and reach it from the other, but since the API require a public constructor, I was forced to imitate the singleton work, and effectively i've reached the instance of the plugin, but i'm enable to reach its properties...

Let me schematize that through simplified code:

let's say this is class A (the one that imitate the singleton)

```
Class A:IPlugin
{
    private static volatile A _instance;
    public static A Instance 
    { 
        get { return _instance; } 
    }
    public A()
    {
        if (_instance == null) _instance = this; // as i'm sure it's called once
    }

    public Foo F{get;set} // THIS IS INITIALIZED SOMEWHERE IN THAT PLUGIN'S CONTEXT
}
```

and this is the class that tries to extract objects from A

```
Class B:IPlugin
{
     FindFoo()
     {
          Foo Fb = A.Instance.F; // THAT IS ALWAYS NULL
     }
}
```

**A very important indication and the one that may create the problem is that:**

**A.F is bound to a WPF control...**

I hope I've clearly transmitted my issue and you'll be able to help me because i'm stuck !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ;

```
public interface IPlugin {
   string Foo { get; set;}
}

public class A : IPlugin {

   private static A _inslance { get; set;}

    public static A Instance {
        get {
            if (_inslance == null){
                _inslance = new A();
            }
            return _inslance;
        }
   }


   public string Foo { get; set;}
}

public class B : IPlugin {

   public string GetMeFooOfA {
        get {
            return A.Instance.Foo;
        }
   }

   public string Foo { get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    A.Instance.Foo = "Test 123";

    var b = new B();

    Console.WriteLine(b.GetMeFooOfA);
}
```

You may want to look at a DI (Dependency Injection), such as Unity, Ninject, etc.. framework which would offer you a good platform to work on when you develop modular code

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I justly have no access to the API classes and interfaces... I can't modify the interface IPlugin

Comment: You don't have to.. its just there so that you could compile the code easily. All you need to have is access to the code of Class A and B